# TravisCI to create APK file in GitHub repository

Tags: android, apk, travis-ci

I have an `Android` repository on `GitHub`, which is builded on `TravisCI`. I try to build `APK` file and upload it to repository.
I use code below for this in `travis.yml` file:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: "myapikey"
  file: "output/apk/sample*release*.apk"
  file_glob: "true"
  skip_cleanup: "true"
  on:
    branch: master
    repo: myuser/myproject
```

I get following message in `TravisCI` build:

```
Installing deploy dependencies
Fetching: multipart-post-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multipart-post-2.0.0
Fetching: faraday-0.13.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed faraday-0.13.1
Fetching: public_suffix-3.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed public_suffix-3.0.0
Fetching: addressable-2.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed addressable-2.5.2
Fetching: sawyer-0.8.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sawyer-0.8.1
Fetching: octokit-4.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed octokit-4.6.2
6 gems installed
Fetching: mime-types-2.99.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-2.99.3
1 gem installed
Preparing deploy
Logged in as myname
Deploying to repo: myuser/myproject
Current tag is: v7
Deploying application
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

There is not any `APK` file in `output/apk/` in my repository.

Comment: You should be able to expand the deploy stage for more verbose output.

Comment: @MattSchuchard : `Deploying application` section is empty.

Comment: This probably means that your glob pattern matched 0 files, all of which were successfully deployed.

Comment: @renemilk : So there weren't any `apk` file generated by `TravisCI`?

Comment: Or in another directory than you think. You can add ```ls output/apk/``` in a prior stage to deploy to make sure.